# Minkowski's Inequality when $0<p<1$

Tags: real-analysis

While $ p \geq 1$ guarentees $\|f+g\|_p \leq \|f\|_p + \|g\|_p$, is it true that for $C>0$ a large constant and $0<p<1$, $\|f+g\|_p \leq C(\|f\|_p + \|g\|_p)$? How would one go about showing this?

Comment: Snip (http://math.stackexchange.com/users/89015/snip), Minkowski's integral inequality in case $0<p<1$, URL (version: 2013-08-22): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/473362

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $0<p<1,$ we have: $$||f+g||_p^p\le ||f||_p^p+||g||_p^p= 1\cdot ||f||_p^p+1\cdot||g||_p^p\le 2^{1-p}\, (||f||_p+||g||_p)^p $$
(by H\"older). Hence, enough to take $C=2^{1/p-1}.$